# Add value to the array in every step of recursion

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have one simple question. How to push a value to the array in every step of recursion? I have a small script that gets content of 10 - 20 urls, gets the image url and it should everytime push the found image url to the array. How to do it?

Comment: You will have to show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by rewriting the function to iteration instead of recursion.

Answer (score 4):

```
$yourArray[] = $newElement;
```

This will push `$newElement` to the end of your array.

Comment: No, I mean something like this - I have 10 pages. On every page I have link to other of these pages (first page contains link to the second, second to the third and so on...) - http://pastebin.com/hTs6m7SL